# Cutomize Swagger UI ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to customize swagger UI on my ASP.NET Core Web API.

I want the UI like this:

[image]

I'm following these tutorials:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?tabs=visual-studio
- https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

This is the Startup.cs configuration:

```
// Add the detail information for the API.
services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    // Determine base path for the application.
    var basePath = _env.WebRootPath;

    // Complete path
    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(basePath, "myapi.xml");

    // Set the comments path for the swagger json and ui.
    options.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
});

app.UseStaticFiles();

// Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
app.UseSwagger();

// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{                
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "MyAPI");
});
```

I already downloaded swagger ui files from the git repository and put on my project like this:

[image]

I don't know if this is the right thing to do, but I'm not able to see any changes to the swagger UI.

Comment: In your `index.html` file are you referencing your css? Also, are your browsing to `http://localhost:<random_port>/swagger/ui/index.html` and entering `http://localhost:<random_port>/swagger/v1/swagger.json` into the input box at the top of the rendered page?

Comment: That's the problem. That index.html page is not called.

Comment: How do you mean, `That index.html page is not called`? Have you tried browsing to it to ensure that it is being served correctly?

Comment: You likely don't need to go to that much effort. Check out my blog post: https://cpratt.co/customizing-swagger-ui-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: I'm mean that index.html inside dist folder isn't the same that loads when I run my API. What I need is to know how to set it correctly to see the changes. The SwaggerEndpoint needs to have a .json file to work.

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes! I was looking to it right before you sent it. Is there a way to set the layout as the one I posted in the question?

Comment: Probably. Just play around with the CSS and JS. What I provided there is entirely just for an example. You can apply whatever CSS or JS you like via your injected files. Between CSS and JS, there's not much you can't change about a layout, but if you find yourself stymied, that might be the point where you need the whole swagger ui distribution. However, I'd consider that the nuclear option, and be prepared to be customizing things heavily, since nothing happens automatically once you go that route.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I just tried the solution on your blog and it works perfectly. But I think I'll go on the entire swagger ui distribution... The layout of the .3x release is awesome. By the way, thank you very much for your explanation! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is using: **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore** unfortunately in that project they still using the Swagger-UI version 2.x, your Screenshot shows version 3.x

There are a few Pull Requests to update to latest Swagger-UI:

- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/453
- https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/pull/543

But unfortunately there is not much progress towards merging those.

I see that you know how to download files from a git repository...
**My recommendation:**
Instead of downloading the swagger-ui files, download the entire project Swashbuckle.AspNetCore from a fork that is using the version you need (such as: [alexvaluyskiy/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore](https://github.com/alexvaluyskiy/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/tree/swaggerui3)), then in your project add a reference to that project instead of the nuget package.

Another option could be creating your own fork of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore merge the fixes you need and then publish your own Nuget package with a different name.

Comment: looks like those issues have been closed

Answer (score 3):

```
//I hope this will help you , you can get //https://localhost:44x22/docs/index.html

        app.UseSwagger(o =>
        {
            o.RouteTemplate = "docs/{documentName}/docs.json";
        });
        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.), 
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        //This line enables Swagger UI, which provides us with a nice, simple UI with which we can view our API calls.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {

            c.IndexStream = () => GetType().Assembly
   .GetManifestResourceStream("CustomUIIndex.Swagger.index.html"); // requires file to be added as an embedded resource
            c.InjectStylesheet("/css/swagger-ui/custom.css");// css path
            c.InjectJavascript("../css/swagger-ui/custom.js"); javascript path
            c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../docs/v1/docs.json", "API v1");
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("../docs/v2/docs.json", "API V2");
        });
        app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue, and I needed to inject my style sheet:

```
c.InjectStylesheet("/Swagger/Ui/custom.css")
```

This was added to `app.UseSwaggerUI` in the Startup.cs file.

The following articles helped, but I had to merge information from both to find my answer:

- https://cpratt.co/customizing-swagger-ui-in-asp-net-core/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio%2Cvisual-studio-xml